# Using time component in dataframe as a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column that contains a str of time as follows:

```
Time
17:24:00
17:25:00
17:26:00
```

and I have already cast the column to datetime as follows:

```
new_data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(new_data['Time'],
                                  format='%H:%M:%S').apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Now the column is in datetime64 as needed and shows:

```
0         1900-01-01 17:24:00
1         1900-01-01 17:25:00
2         1900-01-01 17:26:00
```

My question is as follows: I need to use the different time components of time as selection criteria for filtering. For example:

```
filtered_df = data.loc[(new_data['Time'].Hour == 17 )]
```

or

```
filtered_df = data.loc[(new_data['Time'].Minutes == 24 )]
```

But I cannot figure out how to select the individual components (Hour, Minutes, Seconds) now that I have it converted to datetime.

Comment: Access the `datetime` object via `dt`, e.g. `new_data['Time'].dt.hour`, `new_data['Time'].dt.minute`

Comment: dang - I was SO close! thanks @Jyr